# Scilab gives the error "SCI environment variable not defined." when run in profiling mode

Tags: debugging, error-handling, valgrind, scilab

I am trying to run Scilab in profiling mode as shown [here](https://www.scilab.org/product/man/scilab.html).So I run the following commands

```
$ export SCILAB_VALGRIND_OPT="--db-attach=no --log-file=myfile.txt"
$ scilab-cli -profiling
```

But I get the error

```
 Running profiling of Scilab  :  valgrind --show-below-main=yes --num-callers=12 --demangle=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --smc-check=all --db-attach=yes --gen-suppressions=all --show-below-main=yes --track-origins=yes --suppressions=/usr/share/scilab//tools/profiling/valgrind.supp --db-attach=no --log-file=scilabsegerr.txt /usr/bin/scilab-cli-bin -profiling
valgrind: Unknown option: --db-attach=yes
valgrind: Use --help for more information or consult the user manual.
```

Somehow db-attach is repeated twice.When I just run valgrind and remove db-attach option like the following

```
$ valgrind --show-below-main=yes --num-callers=12 --demangle=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --smc-check=all --gen-suppressions=all --show-below-main=yes --track-origins=yes --suppressions=/usr/share/scilab//tools/profiling/valgrind.supp --log-file=scilabsegerr.txt /usr/bin/scilab-cli-bin -profiling
```

I get the error "SCI environment variable not defined."

Comment: What version of SciLab and Valgrind are you using?

Comment: Seems to be removed from scilab/bin/scilab on 21st of August: [see commit](http://gitweb.scilab.org/?p=scilab.git;a=blobdiff;f=scilab/bin/scilab;h=dad18adc89105cbdb8701adb3f7602b9b8c71d4a;hp=8be3776ed265f9f382bbe3c0f3a121dab86041cd;hb=d15ecc57ad2aa0dbc862bea9540573dcf6c0caa3;hpb=99c1c5614e7ac8862b766469331d3f5101523f9c)

Comment: Note also that db-attach will be removed from valgrind after 3.10 release see [valgrind release notes](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html)

Comment: @spoorcc I am using Scilab 5.5.2 and Valgrind 3.11.0 . 
But even when I run without db-attach,I get the error "SCI environment variable not defined."

Comment: The scilab-cli-bin is the binary and the scilab-cli script defines the needed variables. You can find this script also in the bin folder. 
As quick workaround you could remove the --db-attach from there probably as well.